# Enabling windows authentication for Java application

Tags: java, authentication, spnego, waffle

We are running a Java application hosted on a windows service.

We have the latest version of **Jetty** web server embedded on the java application.

We are running servlets on the Jetty webserver.

We have a VB application and another Java application consuming these servlets.

**We have a requirement:**

- to enable windows authentication on the server application.

**We tried:**

- we tried [**Waffle**](http://dblock.github.io/waffle/) but we are observing memory leak while using that.
- we are reluctant to try **[SPNEGO](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/index.html)** and other Kerberos based solutions because of the amount of configuration required.

Can someone suggest approaches for enabling widows authentication on Java application hosting Jetty server or just help us with Waffle if we are doing something wrong, following is the code that we have to enable windows authentication on Waffle:

```
waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter securityFilter = 
        new waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter();
  FilterHolder filterHolder = new FilterHolder();
  filterHolder.setFilter(securityFilter);  
  EnumSet<DispatcherType> enums = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST);
  enums.add(DispatcherType.REQUEST);  
  servletContext.addFilter(filterHolder, "/*", enums);
```

Comment: What memory leak did you discover with Waffle?

Comment: The java application that is hosting the webserver is called by another java application constantly at a rate of around 40K request per hour. If we are using Waffle on the webserver for windows authentication the server process reaches 1 GB within 2 hrs.

Comment: you should really report that.